# Как получить двойные кавычки в to_char() при преобразовании даты в строку?

Tags: sql, oracle

При запросе:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-"MON"-DD') FROM dual;
```

Я получу:

```
2023-MON-10
```

Но я хочу получить:

```
2023-"JUL"-10
```

Как мне экранировать двойные кавычки в формате to_char()?

Comment: Эскейп последовательстью

Comment: @eri Какой же последовательностью?

Comment: Во многих базах сработает экранирование.

    psql> SELECT to_char(NOW(), 'YYYY-\"MON\"-DD');

Но не в оракл.

Comment: @eri но ведь вопрос именно про оракл... Ладно, видимо ответ, который я принял ниже - действительно единственный.

Comment: поэтому я и не записал ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутри формата двойные кавычки всегда будут иметь "магический" смысл, т.к. эскейп-последовательностей там нет.

Можно подставить другой символ пунктуации, а потом его заменить на кавычки:

```
SELECT replace(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-@MON@-DD'), '@', '"') FROM dual;
```

А можно разбить формат на несколько кусков и потом сконкатенировать кавычки между ними:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')||'-"'||to_char(sysdate, 'MON')||'"-'||to_char(sysdate, 'DD') FROM dual;
```